# Any way to redirect without touching window or document?

Tags: javascript, redirect

Is there any way to cause a page to redirect without having to use window or document?

or some other work around for Adsafe?

```
<div id="REDIR_">

<script>
   ADSAFE.go("REDIR_", function (dom, lib) {
       "use strict";
       window.location = "http://www.google.com";
});
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: You could create a link element and then trigger a click event on the link, or you could create a form and trigger a submit event. But why would you go to the trouble?

Comment: By far the easiest way to do this is server side. Is there anything stopping you doing that? Also, what language are you writing your server scripts in?

Comment: Question doesn't make sense as written. If you explain why you want this, the answers will be more useful.

Comment: Why can't you use document or window? Not doing so is about as non-standard as it gets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try meta data?

```
META http-equiv = "refresh" content = "0; URL = anydomain.com/destination.html"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could document write a meta redirect into the document.

`document.write('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/">');`

Comment: This does still touch "document", though.

Comment: . . . did I just see someone advocate the use of `document.write`?

Comment: @Zach indeed, but I suspect the non use of document or window was more in relation to the associated methods which modern browsers tend to block if they consider it automated and/or potentially malicious? OP to confirm?

Comment: I would think that if the browser blocks window.location as potentially malicious, then they would certainly have a problem with document.write (since you could feasibly inject anything, including more script to run, into the document).

Comment: @LeviMorrison sadly, yes. However, it's difficult to not use window or document to redirect without putting something in. The tags on the question suggest a javascript means by which to do so, so putting this in with javascript is difficult without knowing if the OP is using a framework such as jQuery/Prototype to handle this for them. If we're worried about how the DOM might behave after this then document.write might be a problem but as the OP wants to redirect I suspect it might be OK? Thoughts?